# How to revert todays code changes in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, undo

I am a new WebStorm user, and am wondering how to revert some code changes I made today.

I made some change which disrupted everything, and now I don't know how to see the code before this change (because WebStorm automatically saves changes). `Undo` doesn't go back far enough.  Is there some way to recover a previous version?

Thanks

Comment: Google for "version control systems"

Comment: Menu -> VCS -> Local History (But you should really follow @Nikems advice.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use a version control system (VCS), for instance Git.

However, WebStorm (and IntelliJ and other JetBrains products) have a built-in VCS. If you are lucky, your old code is still there. Select `VCS` -> `Local History` -> `Show history` from the main menu while you have the file open.

This should open a window showing several previous versions of the file.

Comment: Now, I am embaressed which basic think I never heard about. Thanks, I learn a lot today!